# Javascript on top-of-window mouseover?

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I'm seeking an onmouseover event to detect when the mouse hovers the top of the window. I'm only able to find onmouseover events for the whole page. How do I restrict it to just the very top of the window?

There's no "element" on the page I'm trying to attach the event to, as some have suggested. This should work with *any* webpage - I do not have any control over the HTML on the page.

Need only support modern browsers, simplest method possible, no jQuery.

Comment: Put the onmouseover event on the element representing the top of the webpage.

Comment: The `onmouseover` can be added to *any* HTML element, that is any `div`, `p`, `img`, `ul`, anything. Do you have an element that covers the portion of the page you are interested in? Then just add the event to that element.

Comment: Or do you perhaps mean the top of the window, as opposed to the top of the page (difference being that the page moves when you scroll, while the window does not)?

Comment: What do you mean over the top? As in an element on top of another one? Or the top as in the top part?

Comment: I do mean the top of the window. There's no "element" on the page i'm trying to attach the event to, as some have suggested.

Answer (score 5):

The [`onmouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmouseover) can be added to any [HTML element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element), that is any `div`, `p`, `span`, `img`, `ul`, anything. Do you have an element that covers the portion of the page you are interested in? Then just add the event to that element.

If the area where you want to catch the mouse movement doesn't correspond to an actual element, you can do it by adding the [`eventlistener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) to the [`body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) and the check where the pointer is:

```
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    //Check if we are in the top area of the page.
    if(event.pageY < 300) {
        //Do something here.
    }
});
```

If you want it to use the top of the page area of the browser as opposed to the page itself (so that scrolling does not affect where the cut off is on the screen) just use [`clientY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientY) instead of [`pageY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageY).

- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vycc7zro/) for `pageY`.
- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/18u7naj3/) for `clientY`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with the but, but [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vycc7zro/) shows it working with `pageY`.

Comment: looks like the winner! how is it different from cosmycx method above? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32236231/209942

Comment: They are exactly the same when it comes to function (as far as I can tell). It is just a question of style.

Comment: not sure if i'm allowed to expand a question, but i want to do one thing when mouse enters top area, and another thing when mouse LEAVES top area. Maybe stackoverflow wants me to open a new question for that, but then that new question would be a partial duplicate of this question.... :/  This fails: https://jsfiddle.net/vycc7zro/3/

Comment: You should not change the meaning of the question after it is asked. It is OK to ask a new question, you could even reference to this one in it. (The new one should be understandable on its own, though.) Anyway, here is a [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/pgdfvtwe/) to the problem.

Comment: The reason your code fails is that you need to make sure the body is at least 300px high, for instance by including a tall element (`style="height:1000px;"`) in it.

Comment: ok, understood. Now i'm concerned about performance. Won't mousemove fire constantly? If so, then i wonder if there's a way to do a mouseenter event-- but i guess that would require that an html region exists, right? Looks like you're handling this with a "firsttime" flag in your new script, but that doesn't not prevent constant firing, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88047/discussion-between-johny-why-and-anders).

Answer (score 1):

alerts when mouse is at top of page: demo on jsfiddle: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cosmycx/1mLvcw32/)

JS:

```
(function (){//alert at top
    function getPosition(e){
        if (e.pageY < 75) alert('top');//switch to clientY for top of screen
    }
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', getPosition, false);})();
```

EDIT:
use: clientY for top of view screen, as page may be longer, this stays with screen 
use: pageY for top of your website only

Comment: great! works! but how is it different from Anders method below? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32236270/209942

Comment: the function (to alert at top) is a Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) which contains: 1-function get position, and 2-event listener that calls the getPosition function on mouse move, you can add any block code you want to replace the alert. the IIFE is a self executing block of code, you can find more on google.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe works...

```
$('body').on('mouseover', function () { // bind change event to select
        if (event.pageY < 10)
            alert(event.pageY)
    });
```

Comment: this is my favorite so far, because so simple. But not working, what did i do wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/n90v9sqg/

Comment: @johnywhy, try change $('#anything')  insted $('body')